# From dic pandas with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like that:

```
{12: {'Soccer': {'value': 31, 'year': 2013}},
 23: {'Volley': {'value': 24, 'year': 2012},'Yoga': {'value': 3, 'year': 2014}},
39: {'Baseball': {'value': 2, 'year': 2014},'basket': {'value': 4, 'year': 2012}}}
```

and i would like to have a dataframe like this:

```
index                      column     
12         {'Soccer': {'value': 31, 'year': 2013}}
23         {'Volley': {'value': 24, 'year': 2012},'Yoga': {'value': 3, 'year': 2014}}
39         {'Baseball': {'value': 2, 'year': 2014},'basket': {'value': 4, 'year': 2012}}
```

with each nested dictionary set in a unique column, with the row given by the key of the external dictionary. When I use 'from_dict' with orient parameter equal to index, it considers that keys from the nested dictionaries are the labels of the columns and it makes a square dataframe instead of a single column...
Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry guys, I realized it was actually easy :
     s=pd.Series(dic,index=dic.keys())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':d})
```

Or:

```
df = pd.Series(d).to_frame('column')
```

---

```
print (df)
                                               column
12            {'Soccer': {'year': 2013, 'value': 31}}
23  {'Volley': {'year': 2012, 'value': 24}, 'Yoga'...
39  {'Baseball': {'year': 2014, 'value': 2}, 'bask...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [65]: pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=d.keys(), columns=['column'])
Out[65]:
                                               column
12  ({'Soccer': {'value': 31, 'year': 2013}}, {'Vo...
23  ({'Soccer': {'value': 31, 'year': 2013}}, {'Vo...
39  ({'Soccer': {'value': 31, 'year': 2013}}, {'Vo...
```